# XSLT transform with MSXML doesn't use proper encoding

Tags: encoding, xslt, msxml

I'm using [`IXMLDOMDocument::transformNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761399%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from MSXML 3.0 to apply XSLT transforms.  Each of the transforms has an `xsl:output` directive that specifies `UTF-8` as the encoding.  For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                ...
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
                extension-element-prefixes="str math">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" />
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yet the transformed result is always `UTF-16` (and the encoding attribute says `UTF-16`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

Is this a bug in MSXML?

For various reasons, I'd really like to have `UTF-8`.  Is there a workaround?  Or do I have to convert the transformed result to `UTF-8` myself and patch up the encoding attribute?

**Update:**  I've worked around the problem by accepting the `UTF-16` encoding and prepending a byte-order mark, which satisfies the downstream users of the transformed result, but I'm still be interested in how to get `UTF-8` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, BSTRs are all UTF-16. However, I think Michael Ludwig might be on to something here. Have you tried using this method?

```
HRESULT IXMLDOMDocument::transformNodeToObject(
    IXMLDOMNode *stylesheet,
    VARIANT outputObject);
```

You should be able to just use CreateStreamOnHGlobal, stash the resultant IStream ptr into a VARIANT, and pass that in as the outputObject parameter. Theoretically. I haven't actually tried this, though :)

Comment: I didn't RTFM carefully enough.  I didn't realize `transformNodeToObject` could output something other than another DOM object.  All three answers were pointing this direction, but only this one made it clear I was using the wrong method.  Sorry I didn't see your response before the bounty expired.

Comment: No worries -- just glad to help :)

Answer (score 4):

You're probably sending the ouput to a DOM tree or to a character stream, not to a byte stream. If that's the case then it's not MSXML that's doing the encoding, and whatever does do the final encoding has no knowledge of the xsl:output directive (or indeed, of XSLT).

Comment: The output of `transformNode` is a BSTR.  MSXML doesn't seem to offer  a byte stream option.  It's the `transformNode` call that's setting the encoding attribute in the output.  BSTRs are normally `UTF-16`, but they can use single-byte encodings like `UTF-8`.  In fact, I created the IXMLDOMDocument objects with BSTRs of UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: The encoding problem is in the serialization of the transformed output. If using .NET, you'll need to use the Encoding class. Since you mentioned BSTR, I suspect you're using C++. I'm not familiar with its library, but find a method to convert the BSTR to UTF-8 byte stream.

Comment: @Doug D:  Yes, I'm using C++, not .NET.  The encoding is not simply a post-processing step, since the XSLT transform is adding the `UTF-16` encoding/charset attribute in the output itself.  So it seems that I'd have to transcode to UTF-8 *and* tweak the actual output.

Comment: Yes, probably. You can prevent the xml declaration using <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" ..., but it's probably easier just to change UTF-16 to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Supplementing what Michael Kay said (which is spot on, of course), here's a JScript example how to transform to a stream, using the XSLT serialization in the process:

```
// command line args
var args = WScript.Arguments;
if (args.length != 3) {
    WScript.Echo("usage: cscript msxsl.js in.xml ss.xsl out.xml");
    WScript.Quit();
}
xmlFile = args(0);
xslFile = args(1);
resFile = args(2);

// DOM objects
var xsl = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDOCUMENT.6.0");
var xml = xsl.cloneNode(false);

// source document
xml.validateOnParse = false;
xml.async = false;
xml.load(xmlFile);
if (xml.parseError.errorCode != 0)
    WScript.Echo ("XML Parse Error : " + xml.parseError.reason);

// stylesheet document
xsl.validateOnParse = false;
xsl.async = false;
xsl.resolveExternals = true;
//xsl.setProperty("AllowDocumentFunction", true);
//xsl.setProperty("ProhibitDTD", false);
//xsl.setProperty("AllowXsltScript", true);
xsl.load(xslFile);
if (xsl.parseError.errorCode != 0)
    WScript.Echo ("XSL Parse Error : " + xsl.parseError.reason);

// output object, a stream
var stream = WScript.createObject("ADODB.Stream");
stream.open();
stream.type = 1;
xml.transformNodeToObject( xsl, stream );
stream.saveToFile( resFile );
stream.close();
```

You may test using this input:

```
<Urmel>
    <eins>Käse</eins>
    <deux>café</deux>
    <tre>supplì</tre>
</Urmel>
```

And this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think it'll be easy for you to adapt the JScript example to C++.

Comment: Thanks Lumi--exactly what I needed to keep encoding as set in XSL when saving XSL result to file in JavaScript. +1